# Почему не вызывается метод onCreate()?

Tags: java, android

Разбираюсь с `Dagger2` и вот в одной из статей нашел вот такой класс

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static AppComponent component;

    public static AppComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        component = buildComponent();
    }

    protected AppComponent buildComponent() {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .anotherModule(new AnotherModule())
                .modelModule(new ModelModule())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Который удобно использовать для инициализации, но дело в том, что метод `onCreate()` не вызывается и соответственно я получаю `null` когда вызываю метод `App.getComponent().inject(this);`

Сначала я взял и просто сделал вот так:

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static AppComponent getComponent() {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .anotherModule(new AnotherModule())
                .modelModule(new ModelModule())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Но потом подумал, что если было сделано именно так значит зачем то это так сделали))

1. Но тогда почему не срабатывает `onCreate()`?
2. и второй вопрос почему не сделать так как у меня во втором примере?

Comment: Вы считаете, что при каждом обращении за компонентом стоит его строить заново? Т.е. все дерево зависимостей будет пересоздано. И в onCreate создают компонент, чтобы получить ссылку на контекст приложения. Попробуйте DBHelper создать без контекста...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `onCreate()` Вашего класса `App` не вызывается потому, что класс `App` нигде не используется.

Для использования класса `App` (вместо стандартного `Application`) необходимо в `AndroidManifest.xml` к тегу `application` добавить атрибут:

```
android:name=".App"
```

тем самым явно указав, что базовым классом Вашего приложения является созданный Вами класс `App` (а не класс `Application`, который считается базовым *по умолчанию*).

Comment: А если мне не нужно, чтоб класс арр был базовым классом? Базовый класс у меня `MainActivity`... Тогда сделать этот метод статичским как я описал будет правильно?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, У Вас сейчас базовый класс приложения – класс `Application`, не путайте `Activity` и `Application`, это два разных класса.

Comment: аа понял, я чет не задумывался раньше.. Мы просто расширяем стандартный класс `Application` и уже в него добавляем инициализацию... Но чтоб он был принят нужно указать его в манифесте, его имя, верно я понял?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, Да, верно.

Comment: А если разбираетесь в dagger может и тут поможете http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/587234/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-is-bound-multiple-times-%D0%B2-dagger2

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, С этим помочь не смогу.