# Как избавиться от ошибки is bound multiple times в Dagger2?

Tags: java, android, dagger2

Я понял так. Если тебе нужно передать параметры в метод который будет инжектнут, то нужно сделать еще один метод который будет предоставлять для `Dagger` этот параметр.

Вот что есть

```
@Module
class ModelModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
ApiInterface provideApiInterface() {
    return ApiModule.getApiInterface();
}
}
```

Метод который отлично работает. Теперь если нам нужно добавить в этот метод параметр, то нам сразу же нужно и создать метод который будет этот параметр предоставлять

вот так

```
@Module
class ModelModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
int provideInt() {
    return 1;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
ApiInterface provideApiInterface(int i) {
    return ApiModule.getApiInterface(i);
}
}
```

Но все дело в том, что у меня уже есть другой модуль в котором инициализирован метод с возвращающим типом `int`

```
@Module
class AnotherModule {
    @Provides
    Integer getInt(){
        return 3;
    }
}
```

И получается что при запуске я получаю вот такую ошибку

> Error:(11, 10) error: java.lang.Integer is bound multiple times:
>   @Provides @Singleton int com.krokosha.aleksey.daggertwo.ModelModule.provideInt()
>   @Provides Integer com.krokosha.aleksey.daggertwo.AnotherModule.getInt()

Получается я не могу использовать 2 метода которые возвращают одинаковый тип... Но как тогда быть?

Мне нужен он и там и там...

Comment: Если вам нужен именно integer, то заверните его в обертку как XyzSettings, потому что просто int в контейнере валяться не должен. Если у вас что-то другое, то начните с документации по `@Singleton`, потому что эта аннотация явно указывает на присутствие только одного экземпляра в контейнере.

Comment: Можно через Qualifier...

Comment: @Etki а, что в данном случае контейнер в котором не должен валяться `int`? Насчет сингтон ,  я попробовал удалить эти аннотации, но все равно та же ошибка... А вы можете пример привести как должен выглядеть такой код ?

Comment: @YuraIvanov может я что то не понимаю, может библиотека не продумана(хотя я больше склоняюсь к первому)). Это ведь очень стандартная ситуация. Если метод который принимает параметр, как передать туда параметр? Вообще конечно идея в передачей параметров запутанная какае то, чтоб передать параметр нужно создать метод который будет предоставлять нужное значение, при чем возвращаемое значение не должно повторяться ни в одном из методов ни одного модуля... Хотя модулей может быть сколько угодно... Странно. И плюс ко всему если передаваемый параметр не статичны а зависит от чего то...

Comment: Расскажите что вы хотите сделать? Зачем параметры ApiInterface?

Comment: @katso это просто мой тестовый пример для ознакомления. Параметры хочу передать просто, чтоб попробовать как это делается... Наверняка столкнусь с этим в проекте...Вот так

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, Обычно не требуется инжектить int, в реальной жизни вам скорее всего понадобится сложный объект для удовлетворения зависимости, который должен создаваться единым способом, или через Qualifier.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko вы остановились на скоупе Singleton, который подразумевает существование одного объекта каждого типа зависимости. В качестве примеров таких синглтонов могут быть Application[Context], DatabaseHelper, RestService, Gson с заданными один раз [де]сериализаторами и т.д. Они могут зависеть друг от друга и таким образом принимать в качестве параметров друг друга. Это конкретно то, что вы реализуете в своем примере. В то же время ваши инты, которые вы инжектите, смысла не имеют - в данном случае они просто константы, которые в качестве параметров передавать не нужно.

Comment: Если вам таки требуются список синглтонов ApiInterface'ов их можно сделать через Multibinding - в доках надо читать, в принципе не особо сложно... Если модуль входит в [под]компонент с другим скоупом, то параметры замечательно передаются в конструктор модуля и опять же эти int'ы инжектить не нужно, они берутся и передаются как переменные модуля...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В итоге я воспользовался `Qualifier` и получилось вот так

```
@Module
class ModelModule {

@Provides 
@Named("FirstInt")
int provideInt() {
    return 1;
}
}

@Module
class AnotherModule {

@Provides 
@Named("SecondInt")
int provideInt() {
    return 1;
}
}

@Inject
protected ApiInterface apiInterface;

@Inject 
@Named("FirstInt") //or whatever you need
protected Integer valueInt;
```